# 2 DataGridViews with same result?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

need some help with a simple code

This is for Visual Studio c# Win Forms

```
   dgvScad.DataSource = 
   dataProvider.getAttestatiByScad(DateTime.Today.AddDays(dayScad), 
   DateTime.Today);

   dgvProve.DataSource = 
   dataProvider.getAziendaliByScad(DateTime.Today.AddDays(dayScad), 
   DateTime.Today);
```

a

```
        public DataTable getAttestatiByScad(DateTime scadenza1, DateTime scadenza2)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT CONCAT(Dipendenti.cognome, ' ', Dipendenti.nome) AS Nome, Attestati.nome AS Attestato, AssAttestati.scadenza AS Scadenza " +
                " FROM Attestati INNER JOIN(AssAttestati INNER JOIN Dipendenti" +
                " ON AssAttestati.matricola=Dipendenti.matricola) " +
                " ON Attestati.ID=AssAttestati.attestato " +
                " WHERE AssAttestati.scadenza<=@scadenza1 AND AssAttestati.scadenza>=@scadenza2;";

            DataTable dt = db.EseguiQueryWithParams
                (
                sql,
                new SqlParameter("@scadenza1", scadenza1),
                new SqlParameter("@scadenza2", scadenza2)
                );

            return dt;
        }



        public DataTable getAziendaliByScad(DateTime scadenza1, DateTime scadenza2)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Aziendali.nome, Aziendali.scadenza FROM Aziendali WHERE Aziendali.scadenza<=@scadenza1 AND Aziendali.scadenza>=@scadenza2";

            DataTable dt = db.EseguiQueryWithParams
                (
                sql,
                new SqlParameter("@scadenza1", scadenza1),
                new SqlParameter("@scadenza2", scadenza2)
                );

            return dt;
        }
```

```
public DataTable EseguiQueryWithParams(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            apriConnessione();
            string nometab = "dump";
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            try
            {
                adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                if (dset.Tables[nometab] != null)
                    dset.Tables[nometab].Clear();

                adp.Fill(dset, nometab);
                DataTable d = dset.Tables[nometab];
                //d.Columns;
                return d;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
                //throw new System.Exception("Errore nella lettura della tabella");

            }
            finally
            {
                adp.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                ChiudiConnessione();
            }

        }
```

I excpect the output to be different results, but all I see its the same for one DataGridView and the other DataGridView.

Hope you understand what I wronte I'm not so good in English.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `EseguiQueryWithParams`. Can we see that?

Comment: Yep, how can i edit my question?

Comment: Click [edit] under the tags.

Comment: You always return `dset.Tables[nometab];` and that's hard-coded as `string nometab = "dump";` Change the value of `nometab` each time you call the function so the function returns a different `DataTable`

Comment: You solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: How can i "Like you" ahha? Or vote you?

Comment: You could do that if I wrote an answer but I only commented. There's more info about voting in the [help].